# Extract data frame from list and perform findpeaks function on each data frame

Tags: r

I uploaded onto R multiple csv files with 16 columns that have 100 data values, some NA which I learned need to be made into 0 in order for findpeaks to work. For each data frame within the list I want to find the peaks of each individual column. I am able to run the code on an individual data frame so I know there are no issues with the data entered (code below for single data frame extracted from list).

```
peak_info <- lapply(myfiles$dt1, findpeaks, npeaks=6, threshold=4, nups = 2, sortstr=FALSE)
```

But when I try to find peaks of all data frames saved in the list using the following code:

```
peaks <- lapply(myfiles, function(x)  findpeaks(x, npeaks=6, threshold=4, nups = 2, sortstr=FALSE) )
```

I get the following error.

> Error in findpeaks(y, npeaks = 6, threshold = 4, nups = 2, sortstr = FALSE) :
> is.vector(x, mode = "numeric") || length(is.na(x)) == 0 is not TRUE

There are a few more functions I want to use so that is why I opted for function(x). Basically once extracted I don't need to placed the data back in the list. I find the average of the peak and saved them in a new data frame.

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message informs that one of two conditions must be met to run the function:

1. The `x` must be a vector of `numeric` type, or
2. There is no `NA` within `x`.

Becuase `myfiles` is a list, it certainly does not meet the first condition. The error shows that `myfiles` doesn't meet the second condition either.

Maybe this can work as you expected:

```
lapply(myfiles, 
       function(x) lapply(x, 
                   findpeaks, npeaks=6, threshold=4, nups = 2,sortstr=FALSE))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved the issue. I actually ran into another issue with the same data set not sure if you can help. https://stackoverflow.com/q/72482067/19245005